# Can't locate object method <var name> via package <file name> error

Tags: perl

```perl
# Object.pm
sub update {
  $table = $self->DB_TABLE;
...
}
```

The `update` function is triggered when a value is updated and seems to be executed multiple times by other files whose relevant parts look like:

```perl
# Status.pm
use constant DB_TABLE => 'Status';
```

```perl
# Flag.pm
use constant DB_TABLE => 'flag';
```

I don't know the inner workings of this project, but modified `Flag.pm` and `Object.pm` as below because I need to use a different table for updating `flag`.

```perl
# Flag.pm
use constant DB_TABLE => 'flag';
use constnat DB_UPDATE_TABLE => '<Table to use when updating flag>';
```

```perl
# Object.pm
sub update {
    my $table = undef;
    if($self->DB_UPDATE_TABLE) {
      $table = $self->DB_UPDATE_TABLE;
    } else {
      $table = $self->DB_TABLE; 
    }
}
```

When I triggered `sub update`, I get

```
Can't locate object method "DB_UPDATE_TABLE" via package "<Status.pm>" at Object.pm.
```

Is there any way I can check if `DB_UPDATE_TABLE` exists in each file without error? I can add the following line to `Status.pm`, but there are a couple dozen of files like `Status.pm`.

```perl
use constant DB_UPDATE_TABLE => '';
```

I don't know why it is `$self->DB_TABLE` not `$self->{DB_TABLE}` but with the assumption that it is a method... tried the following, but it also had its own error.

```perl
    if( my $ref = eval { $self->can( DB_UPDATE_TABLE ) } ) {
      $table = $self->DB_UPDATE_TABLE;
    } else {
      $table = $self->DB_TABLE; 
    }
```

```
Bareword "DB_UPDATE_TABLE" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at Object.pm => I couldn't find the part to set 'strict subs'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Super close!

```perl
$self->can( DB_UPDATE_TABLE )
```

should be

```perl
$self->can("DB_UPDATE_TABLE")
```